# Randomly sample x% of each cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a project aiming to exploit the cluster structure of my dataset to improve a supervised active learning classifier for binray classification. I use the following code to cluster my data, `X` using scikit-leanr's K-Means implementation:

```
k = KMeans(n_clusters=(i+2), precompute_distances=True, ).fit(X)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster' : k.labels_, 'percentage posotive' : y})
a = df.groupby('cluster').apply(lambda cluster:cluster.sum()/cluster.count())
```

The two classes are positive (represented by a 1) and negative (represented by a 0) and are stored in an array `y`. 
This code first clusters `X` and then stores in a data frame each clusters number and the number of percentage of positive instances within it.

I would now like to randomly select points from each cluster, until I have sampled 15%. How can I do this?

As requested here is a simplified script including a test dataset:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd
X = [[1,2], [2,5], [1,2], [3,3], [1,2], [7,3], [1,1], [2,19], [1,11], [54,3], [78,2], [74,36]]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
k = KMeans(n_clusters=(4), precompute_distances=True, ).fit(X)
df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster' : k.labels_, 'percentage posotive' : y})
a = df.groupby('cluster').apply(lambda cluster:cluster.sum()/cluster.count())
print(a)
```

*Note:* The real datasets are much larger consisting of thousands of features and thousands of data instances.

**In response to [@SandipanDey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706171/sandipan-dey):**

I can't tell you too much, but basically we are dealing with a highly unbalanced dataset (1:10,000) and we are only interested in identifying the minority class examples with recall > 95% whilst reducing the number of labels requested. (Recall needs to be so high as its related to healthcare.)

The minority examples cluster together, and any cluster containing a positive instances will usually contain at least x%, so by sampling x% we ensure that we identify all clusters with any positive instances. So we are able to quickly reduce the size of the dataset with potential positives. This parital dataset can then be used for active learning. Our approach is loosely inspired by ['Hierarchical Sampling for Active Learning'](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw1ezc39HSAhXJhJAKHZE-Ce8QFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.columbia.edu%2F~djhsu%2Fpapers%2Fhier.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE4qlak1VIYFnZtj0WTCI143gFjiw&sig2=puArMM6aI1tYxU2PR1M-_Q)

Comment: I don't think you are representing negative with 1 also. Anyway, you post a (small) example dataset to do this on?

Comment: @Denziloe Good catch, have edited accordingly. Will add small test dataset soon.

Comment: @Denziloe Have added test dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much @scutnex for adding the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the following code should serve the purpose:

```
import numpy as np

# For each cluster 
# (1) Find all the points from X that are assigned to the cluster. 
# (2) Choose x% from those points randomly.

n_clusters = 4
x = 0.15 # percentage

for i in range(n_clusters):

    # (1) indices of all the points from X that belong to cluster i
    C_i = np.where(k.labels_ == i)[0].tolist() 
    n_i = len(C_i) # number of points in cluster i

    # (2) indices of the points from X to be sampled from cluster i
    sample_i = np.random.choice(C_i, int(x * n_i)) 
    print i, sample_i
```

Just for curiosity, how are you going to use these `x%` points for active learning?

Comment: Thanks! Have provided a brief description of approach

Comment: Thank you very much @scutnex for adding the description, really appreciated.